# How to override ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean with JRuby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jruby

I'm trying override the active record class to return true/false instead of 1/0. The example works like a charm with Ruby, but with JRuby not works.

```
module ActiveRecord::Type
  class Boolean    
    def type_cast(value, column = nil)
      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES.include?(value) ? false : true
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you use the same Rails version in your ruby and jruby project ?

Comment: I'd highly advise against monkey-patching like this. You'd be better off just making a module that you can include in your AR classes that can convert the needed attributes there

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk you are right! Running with Ruby 2.1.x works, and not work with JRuby 1.7.x with Ruby 1.9.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running with Ruby 2.1.x works and not work with JRuby 1.7.x/Ruby 1.9.x.
Thanks @ThomasHaratyk